# Erratic behavior of a density plot

Tags: r, density-plot

I have two numerical variables that I plotted in the following by means command `density` in `R`. The code is the following:

```
d0<-density(T0,n=2^14)
df_density0<-data.frame(x=d0$x,y=d0$y,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d1<-density(T1,n=2^14)
df_density1<-data.frame(x=d1$x,y=d1$y,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Initially, I had left the number of equally spaced points `n` at the default value 512, but then I realized that the area under a density plot `d1` was not equal to 1 (it was around 13). Then I selected the proper number `n` in order to obtain an AUC (area under curve) near to 1 for both the density plots. In this way:

```
library(zoo)
x <- df_density0$x
y <- df_density0$y
id <- order(x)
AUC0 <- sum(diff(x[id])*rollmean(y[id],2))

x <- df_density1$x
y <- df_density1$y
id <- order(x)
AUC1 <- sum(diff(x[id])*rollmean(y[id],2))
```

For `n=2^14` I obtained `AUC0` and `AUC1` equal to 0.9999... I plotted these density curves and I obtained the following graphic (blue is for `T0` and red is for `T1`):

[image]

Since these graphs were indistinguishable from each other, I selected a logarithmic scale for the vertical axis:

[image]

Is it possible that I get such a result? Should I change the `kernel` field in the `density` function?

Ps. To draw these graphs I exported `d0` and `d1` in two csv files to import them into LaTeX. Anyway, I obtained the same plots in `R`. Moreover,

```
> nrow(T0)
[1] 9760
> nrow(T1)
[1] 1963
```

Comment: Why `n=2^14`? What are the lengths of `T0` and `T1`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: 9760 and 1963

Comment: This feels to me like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): I suspect the question addresses a symptom rather than the underlying cause.  In any case, I think we need to see the input data before we can give definitive help.